# Strange line appearing

Tags: qgis, line

I have this line in my project's layer which I can't make disappear:

[image: strange line]

I hope you can see it. In QGIS is much more visible. An it also appears on the print composer.

Any suggestions would be very useful.

Comment: I've seen these lines too sometimes but it has never effected my final output.  I have always just put it down to a monitor artifact because I've seen similar things in ArcGIS too.